# Python, модуль re

Tags: python, строки

Имеется код:

```
import re

a = 'Value_1(point_value_s).UMAGValue_2(min_s).WValue_3(max_s).UMAG'

templates = [
    r'Value_1\(.+?\)\..+?',
    r'Value_2\(.+?\)\..+?',
    r'Value_3\(.+?\)\..+?'
]

template = ''
for i in range(len(templates)):
    template += '(%s)|' % templates[i]

print(re.findall(template[:-1], a))
```

Данный код выдает:

```
[('Value_1(point_value_s).U', '', ''), ('', 'Value_2(min_s).W', ''), ('', '', 'Value_3(max_s).U')]
```

Не могу понять, как сделать так, что бы выдавал нечто в роде:

```
[('Value_1(point_value_s).UMAG', '', ''), ('', 'Value_2(min_s).W', ''), ('', '', 'Value_3(max_s).UMAG')]
```

Comment: А вам обязательно через `re` чисто нужно? У меня впечатление, что проще сначала разбить строку по `Value_`, а дальше уже искать шаблоны в найденных кусках.

Comment: Можно попробовать `r'Value_1\(.+?\)\..+?(?=Value_|$)'`  и т.д.  Хотя обратите внимание, кроме цифр 1, 2, 3 там все повторяется, надо как-то упростить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

a = 'Value_1(point_value_s).UMAGValue_2(min_s).WValue_3(max_s).UMAG'
t = 'Value'
g = re.split(t, a)
res = [t + i for i in g if i]
print(res)
```

---

```
['Value_1(point_value_s).UMAG', 'Value_2(min_s).W', 'Value_3(max_s).UMAG']
```